# node.removeChild(child) not working in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a child component that mainly is used to pass props to while the parent component handles most functions however there are a few things the child component should do and one is to remove/delete itself.

I'd tried doing "display none" but the library sortableJS and what I've written doesn't play well together, so I thought I'd try just removing the element all together and since I'm still pretty green at React, Javascript I'm sort of running up against a wall.

In my child component I have:

```
    return (
      <div
        style={{ display: this.state.display }}
        className="group-list"
        ref={sortableGroupDecorator}
        id="cell"
      >
        <CountCell style={{ background: this.state.color }}>

          <Row style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: '-42px' }}>
            <Col>
              <DeleteButton onClick={this.removePeople}>
                <Icon name="delete" className="delete-adjust fa-minus-circle" />
              </DeleteButton>
              <CountButton
                className={this.state.buttonStyle}
                onClick={event => {
                  this.props.incrementCountTotal();
                  this.incrementCount();
                }}
              >
                <Icon
                  name="icon"
                  className={'fa fa-plus ' + this.state.fontAwe}
                />
              </CountButton>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <ScoreName style={{ color: this.state.scoreNameColor }}>
                {this.state.evilName + name}
              </ScoreName>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Score
                style={{
                  color: this.state.scoreColor,
                  textShadow: this.state.glow
                }}
              >
                {this.state.score}
              </Score>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <CountButton
                className={this.state.buttonStyle}
                onClick={event => {
                  this.props.decrementCountTotal();
                  this.decrementCount();
                }}
              >
                <Icon
                  name="icon"
                  className={'fa fa-minus ' + this.state.fontAwe}
                />
              </CountButton>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </CountCell>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the styled component `DeleteButton`onClick calls the function to remove itself which is:

`removePeople() {
    // this.setState({ display: 'none' });
    this.removeChild();
  }`

The display "none" really didn't work well so when I tried `removeChild` (which I don't think is correct) I get the error `this.removeChild is not a function` which is to be expected but I'm unsure what to put in my function that would remove the attribute all together.

(the `display: 'none'` worked well enough until you sorted them, or moved them around and then all of the sudden it would either not work or remove several items at once)

Comment: Can you add a bit more clarity, what specifically are you trying to remove in the code above?

Comment: this is the data contained in a list item populated by an array.  I'd like, within the child, to remove itself (thus removing it from the array generated from the parent... if I do it on the parent, it removes everything in the array).  So everything between the main `<div>`

Comment: I'm still confused. What are you removing? `<CountCell />`? Can you please post the Parent component as well, and create a fiddle if possible.

Comment: yes it'll be a bit but I can do that